# Construct forest plot with bootstrapped confidence intervals

Tags: r, bootstrapping, metafor

I'm developing a multivariate meta-analysis (rma.mv function) with the metafor package.
I've managed to construct the bootstrapped confidence intervals using a function provided by  [Viechtbauer](https://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:bootstrapping_with_ma#non-parametric_bootstrapping). However, I would like to present the bootstrapped confidence intervals in a forest plot, but haven't found a way to do so.

The function code is as follows:

```
boot.function <- function(dat, ID) {
  
 sel <- dat[ID,]
 res <- try(suppressWarnings(rma.mv(yi,
                                     vi,
                                     method = "REML",
                                     random = list( ~ 1 | ID),
                                     mods = ~ practice - 1,
                                     slab = paste(practice, sep = "-"),
                                     test = "t",
                                     dfs = "contain",
                                     data = sel)), 
             silent = TRUE)

  if (inherits(res, "try-error")) {
    NA
  } else {
    c(coef(res), vcov(res), res$sigma2)
  }
  
}
```

I've used the following command to run the bootstrap:

```
set.seed(8781328)
resW.boot <- boot(databaseNBS.W, boot.func, R=1000)
```

I would like to plot the bootstrapped confidence intervals in a forest plot using the forest() function but I haven't managed a way to do it. Is it even possible to do so?